# setting language and locale to my iphone application

Tags: iphone, setlocale

Can I give the choice for user to change the language from inside an application instead of changing the general language of the device?
I am using the regular NSLocale class.

Answer (score 1):

You can.

**Don't.**

There's a reason it's a system-wide setting.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

FYI, in places like Hong Kong, many people would use English as the device language, and only want an app to be in Chinese language when it is a local app (Something like restaurant name, bus information). And since there are many english speakers also, Hong Kong apps usually has in app language setting.

If your app is targeting normal people, you should follow their device language settings.

Comment: is there standard in app language settings in ios ?

Comment: AFAIK, no, i usually implement it myself.